# How to import mysql.connector for Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, python-3.11

im actually doing a python tutorial for doing a web app with mysql database but when importing mysql connector for python it never recognizes its already install.

i have tried configuring the path, installing and reinstalling the connector and the only way it worked was with this command but the compilator still cant understand what mysql.connector is.

`PS D:\IVP\IVP_PY> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe d:/IVP/IVP_PY/src/database.py`

please help i just want to import mysql for my connection to my databse on mysql. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution: i had Python 3.10 and Python 3.11, then i uninstalled the oldest version and it just worked after hours of validations.